# How to perform constraint solving with mixed data types?

Tags: java, constraints, constraint-programming, constraint-satisfaction

I'm working on source-to-source transformer for **Java 6<sup>*1)</sup>**.

I need to maintain negative information as well as positive information, so I have to implement the small *constraint system* for the transformer. The *constraint system* is the restricted kind of CNF formula that can be defined as the following:

`(v1 == c1 /\ v2 == c2 ... vn == cn) /\ 
((w1,1 != d1,1 \/ w1,2 !== d1,2 ... w1,k != d1,k) /\ 
 (w2,1 != d2,1 \/ ...) /\ ... 
 (wm,1 != dm,1 \/ ... \/ wm,k != dm,k))`

where `vi == ci` are **equality constraints** (substitutions, variable assignments),

`wj != dj,l` are **disequality constraints**,

`vi, wj,l` are **variables**,

`ci, dj,l` are **constants** (literals).

**Constant** types are Java primitive types and reference types mapped to integers. Constants are also arbitrary AST-like structures (which represent partially evaluated expressions and possibly contain (meta)-variables).

*Constraint system* works as the following:

When the transformer reaches a conditional (e.g. `if(x == c) then b else b1`) the constraint `x == c` is added to the *constraint system* of *then* branch and the constraint `x != c`, in turn, is added to the *constraint system* (formula) of *else* branch.

So, new formula of *then* branch is: `x == c /\ formula` (positive part of the formula is the conjunction of **equalities**);

new formula of *else* branch is: `x != c \/ formula` (negative part of the formula is the conjunction of disjunctions of **disequalities**).

**Edit:** Satisfiability of the *constraint system*.

For the *constraint system* to be satisfiable it must be possible to assign values to the variables in the system such that constraints are satisfied.

The *constraint system* is thus satisfied iff there exists a substituition *Theta* such that, for each equation `v = c` *Theta*`v` will be syntactically identical to *Theta*`c`, and likewise, for each disequation `w != d` *Theta*`w` will be syntactically different from *Theta*`d`.

Unfortunately, I'm pretty new to constraint programming and I came across the problems.

1. It is not entirely clear for me how to map AST constants to integers in this case.
   Should I simply use the index of the constants' array or some hash function?
2. It is not clear how to handle **long** type. Rewrite int-based solver making it long-based or use floating-point solver?
3. It is also not clear how to handle combined **integer** and **floating-point** data.
   As I realize the straightforward solution is using **floating point** solver for both **integer** and **floating point** constraints. Is it true? Or I can solve **floating-point** and **integer** part of constraints separately?

Please, could someone help me? Some directions, hints ...

<sup>1)</sup> Currently, `source=8 / target=8` scheme is accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be good if you would also post your final goal (what does a solved constraint actually mean).

However, it seems to me that you want to know the set of possible values for each variable at a given statement. In that case you will need an [interval constraint solver](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=interval%20constraint%20solver&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ved=0CB4QgQMwAGoVChMI8t-S4oCwxwIVpmtyCh3dLgER)

The distinction between integer and rational intervals depends on your use case and the solver you choose, but in general it is possible to handle integers as floating points (which might result in non-integer solutions of your constraint).

It is **important** to keep in mind that you will [**not** be able](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) to prove equality of arbitrary AST fragments. Hence, you either need to reduce the expressiveness of said fragments (e.g. polynomials over your variables of a given order) or approximate equality (e.g. referencing the **same** (i.e. same context, same syntax, no side-effects) AST fragment. However, it might be best to just translate AST fragments to unbound (or pessimistically bound) intervals.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  Unfortunately, I found almost nothing about **unbound (or pessimistically bound) intervals**..Do you have any links about that?

Comment: There won't be much literature about that. What I meant is that an unevaluated AST fragment should yield the interval (-∞,∞), or rather (min, max) for whatever your numerical datatype is (eg. Int.MAX).